# Is there a difference between dispatching multiple actions for each particular reducer and dispatching one action for multiple reducers?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a case where I get a data returned from API and I need to arrange this data to each reducer. There are two ways of designing it:

1. Сase when multiple actions are being dispatched to each particular reducer:

```
export function actionFetchData() {
  const data = getDataFromApi()

  dispatch({ type: firstReducer.someAction, payload: { data: data.someProp })
  dispatch({ type: secondReducer.someAction, payload: { data: data.anotherProp })
  // .. and so on
}
```

2. Case when only one generic action is being dispatched and only specific reducers should handle this one:

```
export function actionFetchData() {
  const data = getDataFromApi()
  dispatch({ type: someGenericAction, payload: { data })
}
```

I know that the first option is more controllable, for example, what if I need to pass some another data for an action and handle it in a specific reducer.
But the reduxjs docs says: [**put as much reducer logic as possible in reducers**](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers).

That's confusing. What option is more appropriate when designing store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Redux Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide), we *do* encourage "keeping as much logic as possible in reducers", as well as [modeling actions as "events", not "setters"](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#model-actions-as-events-not-setters).

In this case, there's no need to dispatch two separate actions.  Dispatch *one* action containing all the data from this API response, and let each reducer handle that as appropriate to update its own piece of state.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I use `redux-toolkit` and its own slices, should I use `extraReducers` in each particular reducer to handle "shared" action?

Comment: For at least one slice reducer, yes.  Conceptually, the dispatched action either "belongs" to one of the slices, or none of them.  Slice reducers use the `extraReducers` field to handle any actions that aren't already defined as part of that slice's `reducers` field.